# creating aws IAM Role using cloudformation does not create RolePolicies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm creating an ec2 instance with a role that provides access to kinesis streams and Dynamodb offset Tables. I am using [`aws cloudformation`](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) for that.

**Problem I'm having is while creating the [Streaming Access IAM Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) itself.**

So, I will have following structure,

```
                        has
StreamingAccessRole ----------> RolePolicy1(kinesis:*), RolePolicy2(dynamodb:*)
```

The template to create the AWS IAM role with two policies, one for kinesis and the other for dynamodb :

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "teamIdentifier": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "a28",
      "Description": "Identifier for the team"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "StreamingAccessRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/a28/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "Stream-ConsumerOffset-RW-AccessPolicy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": "kinesis:*",
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:*:stream/a28-*"
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": "dynamodb:*",
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:*:table/a28-*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It creates the Access Role but without role-policies.

```
$ aws iam get-role --role-name a28-streaming-access-role-st-StreamingAccessRole-14QHMTIOIRN5X --region us-west-2 --profile aws-federated
{
    "Role": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17", 
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
                    "Effect": "Allow", 
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "RoleId": "AROAIFD6X2CJXTKLVQNLE", 
        "CreateDate": "2017-04-07T18:54:59Z", 
        "RoleName": "a28-streaming-access-role-st-StreamingAccessRole-14QHMTIOIRN5X", 
        "Path": "/a28/", 
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::500238854089:role/a28/a28-streaming-access-role-st-StreamingAccessRole-14QHMTIOIRN5X"
    }
}
```

Listing the role-policies

```
$ aws iam list-role-policies --role-name a28-streaming-access-role-st-StreamingAccessRole-14QHMTIOIRN5X --region us-west-2 --profile aws-federated
{
    "PolicyNames": []
}
```

which means it did not even create any policies,

```
aws iam list-policies --region us-west-2 --profile aws-federated | grep Stream-ConsumerOffset-RW-AccessPolicy
```

But **if I supplied only `kinesis:*` statement in above example**, it creates a policy, but not with `dynamodb:*` alone.

[image: no policies created]
So, my question is **how am supposed to provide multiple RolePolicies using one cloudformation AWS::IAM::Role template**, or is this specific to dynamodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an intermittent race condition when you create the Policy in the Role.  Create the Policy separately with AWS::IAM::Policy and set the Roles property to the Role.  The problem will go away.

Comment: you sound like the one who created the bug in first place. I simply tried with dynamo policy and referenced to the role and it did work, I will for problem and see. Thanks

Comment: Nope.  I found it through a lot of pain and AWS support admitted to it and admitted they know about it and that it is not documented

Comment: It seems like these types of bugs are prevalent in the AWS ecosystem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your template worked perfectly fine for me.

I ran your template and then:

```
$ aws iam get-role --role-name stack1-StreamingAccessRole-1KDUTVG1OLLQM
{
    "Role": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17", 
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
                    "Effect": "Allow", 
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "RoleId": "AROAJADV75HTIM6C62YXQ", 
        "CreateDate": "2017-04-08T22:22:21Z", 
        "RoleName": "stack1-StreamingAccessRole-1KDUTVG1OLLQM", 
        "Path": "/a28/", 
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/a28/stack1-StreamingAccessRole-1KDUTVG1OLLQM"
    }
}
```

Listing the role-policies:

```
$ aws iam list-role-policies --role-name stack1-StreamingAccessRole-1KDUTVG1OLLQM
{
    "PolicyNames": [
        "Stream-ConsumerOffset-RW-AccessPolicy"
    ]
}
```

The policy is attached as an **inline policy**, so it will not appear in `list-policies`. Rather, use `get-role-policy` to view it:

```
$ aws iam get-role-policy --role-name stack1-StreamingAccessRole-1KDUTVG1OLLQM --policy-name Stream-ConsumerOffset-RW-AccessPolicy
{
    "RoleName": "stack1-StreamingAccessRole-1KDUTVG1OLLQM", 
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17", 
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "kinesis:*", 
                "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:*:stream/a28-*", 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }, 
            {
                "Action": "dynamodb:*", 
                "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:*:table/a28-*", 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "PolicyName": "Stream-ConsumerOffset-RW-AccessPolicy"
}
```

Comment: Thanks John for your answer. Strange things happening with my company account. I checked the aws UI as well and saw the policy disappears in a while. I have been trying this for days but could not succeed. I feel like there're some restrictions creating policies. Can you suggest me a way I can debug why policies not being attached. `aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name a28-streaming-access-stack --region us-west-2` does not provide much info.

Comment: Its working only with `kinesis:*` role policy, but not with `dynamodb:*`, which is very strange.

Comment: Disappearing resources suggests that the CloudFormation template is being deleted or rolled-back. Check that is still says `CREATE_COMPLETE` and look at the Resources tab to examine what has been created.

Comment: Yes, the status is still `CREATE_COMPLETE`. Its weird that its not adding `dynamodb:*` actions. But works fine with `kinesis:*` only.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be race condition as already answered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443883/432903) by Tim Bassett, I simply wanted to add final solution that worked, and how to add [`AWS::IAM::Policy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html) to cloudformation.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Some Streaming api devops",
  "Parameters": {
    "environment": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "staging",
      "Description": "environment"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "StreamingAccessRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": "StreamingAccessRole",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/a28/"
      }
    },
    "StreamConsumerOffsetRWAccessPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:*"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                "*"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "kinesis:*",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:051620159240:stream/a28-*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteTable",
                "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:GetRecords",
                "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
                "dynamodb:ListStreams",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:051620159240:table/a28-*"
            },
            {
              "Action": [
                "sns:*Permission",
                "sns:Create*",
                "sns:Delete*",
                "sns:Publish",
                "sns:ReceiveMessage",
                "sns:Set*"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:051620159240:a28-*"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow"
            }
          ]
        },
        "PolicyName": "StreamConsumerOffsetRWAccessPolicy",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "StreamingAccessRole"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```